# Getting method name inside sublime snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
A = {
    x : funciton(){

    },
    y : function(){

    }
}
```

**What do I want?**

I want to write a sublime snippet which when invoked **inside** `x` or `y` function, should be able to get the function name and put it.

Example - The **DocBlockr** plugin automatically gets the name/arguments of a method before which you create the block by hittin `/**` and hit `Enter`

I know how to write basic snippets but not sure whether a snippet can get the names or tokens from a file. Not even sure if it is possible.

NOTE - I could not do much by myself as I cant figure out where to start for this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Snippets. They cant "look" at the surrounding code and do actions based on that. You would have to write a Sublimetext-plugin do to that.

Looking at the sourcecode of DocBlockr should give you an idea how to do that; The file jsdocs.py contains methods like `parseFunction()` and `getArgType()`, which extract the functionname and parameters using Regular Expressions.

Comment: that makes me sad. :(

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: this doesn't directly answer the question, but chances are it solves your problem - if it happens that you just need it for debugging purposes. I'd submit it as a comment, but not enough reputation yet.

Try this:

```
arguments.callee.name
```

However note:

- this is not a ST feature, it's a **JS feature** to get function name
- this feature is actually discouraged, chances are it can hurt performance - so **development mode only**
- it's actually **forbidden** in strict mode
- it won't work with anonymous functions like in your snippet - you will need to give your functions a name `x: function x() {}`
- some browsers may not support name properties for functions